# Select Required validation not working in form

Tags: html, validation, html-select, required

The "required" validation is working for form

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<form action=''>
<select required>
  <option value="">None</option>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab" >Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
<input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

but is not working for the same form if I move the option with empty value down the list.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<form action=''>
<select required>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab" >Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  <option value="">None</option>
</select>
<input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Why?
How exactly does the select element validation work?

Referred to the following: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_select_required.asp

Comment: _“Why?”_ - well simply because it was _specified_ this way … https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sec-forms.html#the-select-element

Comment: There must be a reason for this specified behaviour. @CBroe

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The following is from w3 [docs](https://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-author-view/the-select-element.html#the-select-element):

> The required attribute is a boolean attribute. When specified, the
>   user will be required to select a value before submitting the form.
>
> ...
>
> if the value of the first option element in the select element's
>   list of options (if any) is the empty string
>
> ...

Which means that the required attribute works only if the value of the first element is empty

Comment: this worked for me, just made sure the first <option> element had an attribute of `value=""`

Answer (score 1):

It's not an issue with Select2 but with the way browser work with select tag. By default, the first option is selected by the browser.
So, in the first case "None" option is selected and hence your validation catch the error because the first option value is null. 
In the second, case the first option is not null. Hence there is no validation error in this case.

To correct it, add an empty option with an empty value and set the attribute as `selected disabled`

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/rLmztr2d/2909/

HTML:

```
<form>
  <select required id="example">
  <option disabled selected></option>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab" >Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  <option value="">None</option>
</select>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

JS:

```
    $('#example').select2();
```

Comment: @K K  Even in this case, if I select the option with value="", the validation does not work. I was hoping to understand this behaviour.